# How to visulize the convolution layer and feature layer in mxnet after cnn was finished trained?

Tags: r, layer, convolution, mxnet, visualize

I want to plot or visualize  the result of each layers out from a trained CNN with mxnet in R. Like w´those abstract art from what a nn's each layer can see.

But I don't know how. Please somebody help me. One way I can think out is to put the weights and bias back to every step and plot the step out. But when I try to put `model$arg.params$convolution0_weight` back to `mx.symbol.Convolution()`, I get

```
Error in mx.varg.symbol.Convolution(list(...)) : 
  ./base.h:291: Unsupported parameter type object type for argument weight, expect integer, logical, or string.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I thought out one way, but encounter a difficulty at one step. Here is what I did.
I found all the trained cnn's parameters in`model$arg.params` , and to compute with parameters we can use mx.nd... founctions as bellow:

`#convolution 1_result

```
conv1_result<- mxnet::mx.nd.Convolution(data=mx.nd.array(train_array),weight=model$arg.params$convolution0_weight,bias=model$arg.params$convolution0_bias,kernel=c(8,8),num_filter = 50)

str(conv1_result)

tanh1_result<-mx.nd.Activation(data= conv1_result, act_type = "sigmoid")
pool1_result <- mx.nd.Pooling(data = tanh1_result, pool_type = "avg", kernel = c(4,4), stride = c(4,4))
```

## conv2 result

```
conv2_result<- mxnet::mx.nd.Convolution(data=pool1_result,weight=model$arg.params$convolution1_weight,bias=model$arg.params$convolution1_bias,kernel=c(5,5),num_filter = 50)
tanh2_result<-mx.nd.Activation(data= conv1_result, act_type = "sigmoid")
pool2_result <- mx.nd.Pooling(data = tanh1_result, pool_type = "avg", kernel = c(4,4), stride = c(4,4))
```

## 1st fully connected layer result

```
flat_result <- mx.nd.flatten(data = pool2_result)
fcl_1_result <- mx.nd.FullyConnected(data = flat_result,weight = model$arg.params$fullyconnected0_weight,bias = model$arg.params$fullyconnected0_bias, num_hidden = 500)
tanh_3_result <- mx.nd.Activation(data = fcl_1_result, act_type = "tanh")
```

## 2nd fully connected layer result

```
fcl_2_result <- mx.nd.FullyConnected(data = tanh_3,weight = model$arg.params$fullyconnected1_weight,bias = model$arg.params$fullyconnected1_bias, num_hidden =100)`
```

but when I came to    `mx.nd.FullyConnected()`  step , I encountered not sufficient memory(i have 16 GB RAM) and R crashed.
So, does anyone know how to batch_size the input data in 
   `mx.nd.FullyConnected()`, or any method to make `mx.nd.FullyConnected()` run successfully as `mx.model.FeedForward.create()`
     did?

Comment: Posting this as an "answer" discourages people who might answer it from looking at your question. You should either [edit] your question, or post a new one with the relevant details to focus on the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that can help you to achieve what you want. The code below displays activations of 2 convolution layers of LeNet. The code gets as an input MNIST dataset, which is 28x28 grayscale images (downloaded automatically), and produces images as activations.

You can grab outputs from executor. To see the list of available outputs use `names(executor$ref.outputs)`

The result of each output is available as a matrix with values in [-1; 1] range. The dimensions of the matrix depends on parameters of the layer. The code use these matrices to display as greyscaled images where -1 is white pixel, 1 - black pixel. (most of the code is taken from https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/1152 and massaged a little bit)

The code is a self sufficient to run, but I have noticed that if I build the model second time in the same R session, the names of ouputs get different indices, and later the code fails because the expected names of outputs are hard coded. So if you decide to create a model more than once, you will need to restart R session.

Hope it helps and you can adjust this example to your case.

```
library(mxnet)

download.file('https://apache-mxnet.s3-accelerate.dualstack.amazonaws.com/R/data/mnist_csv.zip', destfile = 'mnist_csv.zip')
unzip('mnist_csv.zip', exdir = '.')

train <- read.csv('train.csv', header=TRUE)

data.x <- train[,-1]
data.x <- data.x/255
data.y <- train[,1]

val_ind = 1:100

train.x <- data.x[-val_ind,]
train.x <- t(data.matrix(train.x))
train.y <- data.y[-val_ind]

val.x <- data.x[val_ind,]
val.x <- t(data.matrix(val.x))
val.y <- data.y[val_ind]

train.array <- train.x
dim(train.array) <- c(28, 28, 1, ncol(train.x))

val.array <- val.x
dim(val.array) <- c(28, 28, 1, ncol(val.x))

# input layer
data <- mx.symbol.Variable('data')
# first convolutional layer
convLayer1 <- mx.symbol.Convolution(data=data, kernel=c(5,5), num_filter=30)
convAct1 <- mx.symbol.Activation(data=convLayer1, act_type="tanh")
poolLayer1 <- mx.symbol.Pooling(data=convAct1, pool_type="max", kernel=c(2,2), stride=c(2,2))
# second convolutional layer
convLayer2 <- mx.symbol.Convolution(data=poolLayer1, kernel=c(5,5), num_filter=60)
convAct2 <- mx.symbol.Activation(data=convLayer2, act_type="tanh")
poolLayer2 <- mx.symbol.Pooling(data=convAct2, pool_type="max",
                                kernel=c(2,2), stride=c(2,2))

# big hidden layer
flattenData <- mx.symbol.Flatten(data=poolLayer2)
hiddenLayer <- mx.symbol.FullyConnected(flattenData, num_hidden=500)
hiddenAct <- mx.symbol.Activation(hiddenLayer, act_type="tanh")
# softmax output layer
outLayer <- mx.symbol.FullyConnected(hiddenAct, num_hidden=10)
LeNet1 <- mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput(outLayer)


# Group some output layers for visual analysis
out <- mx.symbol.Group(c(convAct1, poolLayer1, convAct2, poolLayer2, LeNet1))
# Create an executor
executor <- mx.simple.bind(symbol=out, data=dim(val.array), ctx=mx.cpu())


# Prepare for training the model
mx.set.seed(0)
# Set a logger to keep track of callback data
logger <- mx.metric.logger$new()
# Using cpu by default, but set gpu if your machine has a supported one
devices=mx.cpu(0)
# Train model
model <- mx.model.FeedForward.create(LeNet1, X=train.array, y=train.y,
                                     eval.data=list(data=val.array, label=val.y),
                                     ctx=devices, 
                                     num.round=1, 
                                     array.batch.size=100,
                                     learning.rate=0.05, 
                                     momentum=0.9, 
                                     wd=0.00001,
                                     eval.metric=mx.metric.accuracy,
                                     epoch.end.callback=mx.callback.log.train.metric(100, logger))


# Update parameters
mx.exec.update.arg.arrays(executor, model$arg.params, match.name=TRUE)
mx.exec.update.aux.arrays(executor, model$aux.params, match.name=TRUE)
# Select data to use
mx.exec.update.arg.arrays(executor, list(data=mx.nd.array(val.array)), match.name=TRUE)
# Do a forward pass with the current parameters and data
mx.exec.forward(executor, is.train=FALSE)
# List of outputs available.
names(executor$ref.outputs)


# Plot the filters of a sample from validation set
sample_index <- 99 # sample number in validation set. Change it to if you want to see other samples

activation0_filter_count <- 30 # number of filters of the "convLayer1" layer 
par(mfrow=c(6,5), mar=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))  # number of rows x columns in output
dim(executor$ref.outputs$activation0_output)

for (i in 1:activation0_filter_count) {
  outputData <- as.array(executor$ref.outputs$activation0_output)[,,i,sample_index]
  image(outputData,
        xaxt='n', yaxt='n',
        col=gray(seq(1,0,-0.1)))
}

activation1_filter_count <- 60 # number of filters of the "convLayer2" layer 

dim(executor$ref.outputs$activation1_output)
par(mfrow=c(6,10), mar=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)) # number of rows x columns in output
for (i in 1:activation1_filter_count) {
  outputData <- as.array(executor$ref.outputs$activation1_output)[,,i,sample_index]
  image(outputData,
        xaxt='n', yaxt='n',
        col=gray(seq(1,0,-0.1)))
}
```

As a result you should see the following images for a validation sample #2 (use RStudio left and right arrows to navigate between them).

[image: First layer activations]

[image: Second layer activations]